# Excel IF Statements Table Format

Tags: excel

Can somebody help me with the following IF statement please. 
I tried the following

```
IF(A2="",D1,IF(D1="",A1,IF(A2=A2,"",D1)))
```

but it doesn't seem to produce correct answer.

Unfortunately i can't post my excel s/h image.

I need to make sure that

```
IF (Cell = number)
  //return as blank
ELSE IF(Cell = no number)
  // return number from Cell that has the number
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't A2=A2 always going to evaluate to true?

Comment: To read your formula back in layman's terms:  If A2 is empty, Use D1.  Otherwise, if D1 is empty, use A1, and lastly, if those aren't true, If A2 is equal to itself, the NOTHING gets input, or else use D1.  What are you getting in the result?  and may I ask which cell this is the formula for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate this formula:

```
IF (Cell = number)
  //return as blank
ELSE IF(Cell = no number)
  // return number from Cell that has the number
```

To worksheet formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"",B1)
```

This assumes `A1` is the cell to test and `B1` is the cell to return if `A1` is *not* a number.

If you need to "chain" these formulas (for example if you also need to verify `B1` is a number as well), you can just place the same into the Else portion of the `IF` statement:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"",IF(ISNUMBER(B1),"",C1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used some of the formula that you have suggested but I have amend it, otherwise the function didn't work.I have used the following function =IF(ISNUMBER(A3),"",IF(D2="",A2,D2)) and it worked.

Comment: @lina1 - Glad to help. If this resolved your issue, then please mark as the answer so the question will be closed. Cheers.